# UICollectionView crashing after scroll and selecting cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `Horizontal CollectionView` which has cells with one `image view` inside. What i want to do is set a default selected cell. Selected cell should change its image color. And after if user select some other cell it should be selected and default selected cell should be deselected. Currently all of those are working. But sometimes when i'm scroll and selecting a cell its crashing saying as follow.

> ERROR: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my complete code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.collectionView.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return CatNames.count
        }


        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CategoryCell
                cell.CarImage.image = UIImage(named: CatImages[indexPath.row])?.maskWithColor(UIColorFromRGB(0xEA7C6A))
                cell.Name.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xEA7C6A)

        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CategoryCell
                cell.CarImage.image = UIImage(named: CatImages[indexPath.row])
                cell.Name.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

            cell.Name.text = CatNames[indexPath.row]


            // setup selectedBackgroundView
            if(cell.selected == true){
                cell.CarImage.image = UIImage(named: CatImages[indexPath.row])!.maskWithColor(UIColorFromRGB(0xEA7C6A))
                cell.Name.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xEA7C6A)
            }
            else{
                cell.CarImage.image = UIImage(named: CatImages[indexPath.row])
                cell.Name.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            }


            return cell
        }


        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            self.collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
        }

extension UIImage {
    func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {

        let maskImage = self.CGImage
        let width = self.size.width
        let height = self.size.height
        let bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue) //needs rawValue of bitmapInfo

        CGContextClipToMask(bitmapContext, bounds, maskImage)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmapContext, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(bitmapContext, bounds)

        //is it nil?
        if let cImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext) {
            let coloredImage = UIImage(CGImage: cImage)

            return coloredImage

        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: highlight the error message

Comment: And show us at least the line where it crashes, in which method?

Comment: i've tryed to print the indexPath.row in didSelectItemAtIndexPath method and issue is indexPath return nil value. This is the error message im getting- fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            guard collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) != nil else {
                  return
            }
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CategoryCell
            cell.CarImage.image = UIImage(named: CatImages[indexPath.row])?.maskWithColor(UIColorFromRGB(0xEA7C6A))
            cell.Name.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xEA7C6A)

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            guard collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) != nil else {
                  return
            }
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CategoryCell
            cell.CarImage.image = UIImage(named: CatImages[indexPath.row])
            cell.Name.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    }
```

This basically answers your question because on this part of your code

```
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CategoryCell
```

You're basically hard casting it using `as!` and the app will crash if the value of `collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)` is nil

Alternatively you can also use the `if let` syntax instead of `guard else`

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    let aCell = cell as! CategoryCell
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Holy Swift!! Thanx a lot for saving my day. Appreciate it.